# Is it possible to access GPIO9 and GPIO10 as DIO?

Tags: nodemcu

I have a nodemcu dev board with the esp12 chip. (Not the esp12e one).

I have tried to make use of gpios 9 & 10 for digital output. On the board, they are marked as SD2 & SD3. I suppose they must be serial data pins by default.

Ideally you can change the pin functions using the PIN_FUNC_SELECT() macro. So I tried the following:

```
PIN_FUNC_SELECT(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_SD_DATA3_U, FUNC_GPIO10);
```

However, on flashing this code, I notice my MCUs reboots. So it must have crashed at some point.

Am I doing this right?

PS: I was hoping to have at least 12 pins that can serve as digital output.

Comment: do you compile and flash with DOUT flash mode? btw SD label is not "serial data", but from SDIO a protocol for SDIO card (they are similar to SD card but not same).

Comment: I use platformio ide to do all the flashing

Comment: `board_build.flash_mode = dout`

Comment: https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/SPI-Flash-Modes

Comment: Yes that seemed to make a difference. However GPIO9 still has the same problem.

Comment: with DIO set at build the mux setting should not be necessary

Comment: I am hoping we can make time and work together and nail this. Join here and mention availability: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110184/nodemcu-users

Comment: sorry, I don't know what else you could try. and I don't have a NodeMcu. other esp8266 boards and modules don't break this pins out. so I never tested this.